# Validating JSON Response using Beanshell in jmeter

Tags: java, json, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to assert Json response in my jmeter using Beanshell assertion . Here is my code below.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.lang.String;
import org.apache.log.Logger;

try{
  String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
  JsonObject jsonobj = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString);
  JsonArray jsonarr = jsonobj.get("items").asArray();
  String pickup = jsonarr.get(2).asObject().get("CM_NAME").asString();
  log.info(pickup); 
 }
catch(Exception e)
{
 log.info("beanshell Exception "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Here is the Json path which i have to validate

```
$.items[2].CM_NAME
```

After i run the script i get the following script.

> Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException:
>   Error   invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of:
>   ``import org.json.JSONObject; import org.json.JSONArray; import
>   java.lang.String;  . . .   '' : Typed variable declaration : Class:
>   JsonObject not found in namespace

I am using jmeter version `2.11`. Can anyone help me to get my script working correctly and is my code correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) instead, which is exactly doing what you want to do.

Also, upgrade to JMeter 3.1 which already embeds this library in its classpath, or download the JAR file and put it in /lib/ext.

Full code example:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

String author0 = JsonPath.read(document, "$.store.book[0].author");
Failure = !"John Smith".equals(author0);
if (Failure) {
  FailureMessage = "Expected John Smith as author";
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibe way to implement it using beanshell assertion.

Comment: Sure, extract the content to check from the response using the library, then check a condition on it like this: if (!condition) IsSuccess = false;

Comment: can you also help me with the imports (as i am using 2.11 version) which we can use in the above example or code and also the JsonPath is a Jar which i have to download from maven repository ?

Comment: Download the JAR from Maven repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0), put it in lib/ext and restart JMeter.

Comment: I have downloaded the jar file from the repository .Restarted my jmeter and included the above import in my beanshell assertion.But still i am getting this error--------- org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.json.JSONObject; import org.json.JSONArray; import java.lang.String;  . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Undefined argument: document

Comment: can i also know how you are getting the response in above code.

Comment: what does 'document' refers?. is it userdefined variable for storing response or jmeter's own varible?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go this way you need to ensure you have the [relevant JSON library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) somewhere in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (usually it is enough to drop the jar to JMeter's "lib" folder and restart JMeter to pick it up)

---

Going forward I would recommend using different approaches like:

1. There is [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/), you can use your JSON Path query directly there. You can install JSON Path Assertion via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JSON Plugins JMeter Plugin Manager]
2. Switch to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language. Groovy has [built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so you won't require any extra libraries. For example if you have the following JSON Response:

   ```
   {
     "items": [
       {
         "CM_NAME": "foo"
       },
       {
         "CM_NAME": "bar"
       },
       {
         "CM_NAME": "baz"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   and you need to extract `baz` value you can do it using the following Groovy code:

   ```
   def response = SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString()
   def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

   log.info(json.items[2].CM_NAME)
   ```

   [image: Groovy JSON Example]

Comment: I am new to jmeter so can you tell me or give me an example on how we can fix this issue in JSR223 Assertion

Comment: I've slightly updated my answer to include an example, check this out. Also I would recommend getting familiarized with [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article